# RSS/Atom feed reader available for ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, rss, feed

I'm looking for some RSS/Atom feed reader available for ASP.NET Core, because `SyndicationFeed` hasn't been ported yet. Do you know some library which could you recommend me?

Answer (score -3):

Let me google that for you:

- [nuget tags: rss](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22rss%22)
- [nuget tags: feed](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22feed%22)

voila: [SimpleFeed on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleFeedReader/) points to this github page: https://github.com/RobThree/SimpleFeedReader

## Todo

- `git clone https://github.com/RobThree/SimpleFeedReader`
- add project.json file
- `dotnet build`
- add dependencies and fix errors (possible changes in dotnet core system libs)
- `dotnet pack -c Release`
- upload package to nuget under other or same name.

And voila use the package :)

(it will take you roughly 1-2 hours)

Comment: It also use SyndicationFeed, so that isn;t solve my problem.

Comment: @Cieja i see, did you find any other solutions?

Comment: I've decided to write my own feed reader, so I think we can close issue.

Comment: @cactodevcie have you made the feed reader available on e.g. github? It could be helpful for other developers